# Coding theory - Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, theory

Here's the question and my attempt at solving it, but after debugging I realized that my while loop is not functioning as needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question: Given an alphabet q, create a list of combinations (with replacement) of size n from the alphabet. If there are at least M elements in the list of combinations, where each elements differs from the rest by d list items, return True.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def nmdcode(q, n, M, d):
    combinations = list(it.product(q, repeat=n))
    final_list = []
    
    i = 0
    n = 0
    
    final_list.append(combinations[0])
    checker = []
    result = False
    
    while i < (len(combinations) - 1):
        checker = combinations[i + 1]
        for element in final_list:
            diff = sum(map(lambda x,y: bool(x-y),checker, element))
            if (diff == d):
                final_list.append(checker)
                print(final_list)
        
        i += 1
    
    if (len(checker) >= M):
        result = True
        
    return result
    
print(nmdcode([1,2,5], 10, 200, 3))
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood when I run to debug our print out my final_list, it's the same appended list over and over. Do I add that to the post?

Comment: @Lebcode your logic is wrong, when you loop over `final_list` and calculate `diff` you repeatedly append the same entry every time the diff is good, you need to only append the entry if every diff is good

Comment: you can replace `bool(x-y)` by `x==y`

Comment: What does *"where each elements differs from the rest by d list items"* mean?

Comment: @Stef if d = 3 then at least 3 elements will be different in each list

Comment: This problem sounds like it should not be solved with bruteforce, but just with a combinatorics argument. The actual input list doesn't matter at all, only the number of unique items in it?

Comment: @nadapez surely `x != y`?

Comment: yes .. mi mistake

Comment: A bruteforce algorithm would have to check every set in the powerset of `Q**n` (cartesian product of Q with itself n times). That's `2**(|Q|**n)` sets to consider. For each set, you want to check whether each pair of elements in this set differ by at least `d` coordinates. For a set of length k, that's `k(k-1)/2` pairs to consider, and the test takes time complexity proportional to the length of the elements, which is n. Most of those sets have size at least n/2. So the total time complexity of a bruteforce algorithm is `2**(|Q|**n) * n**3`. With |Q| = 5, n=2, d=2, that's already 270000000.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified code to work

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

def nmdcode(q, n, M, d):
    combinations = list(it.product(q, repeat=n))
    final_list = []
    
    i = 0
    n = 0
    
    # final_list.append(combinations[0])
    checker = []
    result = False
    
    
    #while i < (len(combinations) - 1):
    for checker in combinations:
        #checker = combinations[i + 1]
        for element in final_list:
            diff = sum(map(lambda x,y: bool(x-y),checker, element))
            #if (diff == d):
            if diff != d:
                break
        else:
            final_list.append(checker)
            print(final_list)
        
        #i += 1
    
    if (len(checker) >= M):
        result = True
        
    return result
    
print(nmdcode([1,2,5], 10, 200, 3))
```

Start with an empty `final_list`.

Loop over the combinations checking if the condition to be in `final_list` fails.

If it fails `break` the loop jumping over the `else` block.

If the condition does not fail, the `else` block is executed, appending the element to `final_list`.

At the beginning `final_list` is empty so the loop just goes directly to the `else` block and append the first element of `combinations` to `final_list`.

Comment: Another bug: `if (len(checker) >= M):` should be `if len(final_list) >= M:`

Comment: @user3386109 Or just `return (len(final_list) >= M)`